# Pandas Carga mal fechas en Python 3

Tags: python

Estoy programando una tarea en Python pero al cargar las fechas de un CSV utilizando Pandas las carga de forma errona, a veces cambia el día por el mes. Por ejemplo, para estos casos todos deberían ser del mes 06, pero a veces es 06 y otras intercambia el 06 por el día, cambiando el mes, por el ejemplo la fila 19 al 23, la 27 y 28:

```
   ......
   19   2017-03-06 01:10:00
   20   2017-03-06 01:10:00
   21   2017-03-06 17:44:00
   22   2017-03-06 17:44:00
   23   2017-04-06 04:12:00
   24   2017-06-06 04:21:00
   25   2017-06-06 04:21:00
   26   2017-06-06 15:37:00
   27   2017-09-06 18:43:00
   28   2017-09-06 18:43:00
   29   2017-09-06 21:59:00
   ....
```

Cargo el archivo de esta forma y creo lista de fechas:

```
   df = pd.read_csv('PORFA.csv', header=0, sep=';')
   Date2=pd.to_datetime(df["FDE Date"]) #Crear lista de Fechas
```

Pero al imprimier "Date2" lo arroja como está arriba.

Adjunto la BBDD que estoy leyendo:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11sJdX_AaJBRllVVjdkenE3RzA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que por defecto intenta parsear la fecha interpretando que el mes va antes que el dia, cuando se encuentra con una fecha incongruente lo intenta usando el primer dato como el dia. Esto hace que no obtengas excepciones.

Tu fecha tiene el formato `dd-mm-aaaa` por lo que debes indicarle que intente usar el primer dato como dia y no como mes. Para esto usa el atributo [`dayfirst`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('PORFA.csv', header=0, sep=';')
Date2=pd.to_datetime(df["FDE Date"], dayfirst = True)
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> Date2
...
19   2017-06-03 01:10:00
20   2017-06-03 01:10:00
21   2017-06-03 17:44:00
22   2017-06-03 17:44:00
23   2017-06-04 04:12:00
24   2017-06-06 04:21:00
25   2017-06-06 04:21:00
26   2017-06-06 15:37:00
27   2017-06-09 18:43:00
28   2017-06-09 18:43:00
29   2017-06-09 21:59:00
...
```

> **Aviso:** `dayfirst = True` no es estricto, esto significa que siempre intentará parsear la fecha usando el primer dato como dia, pero si se encuentra con una fecha que no es parseable de esta forma, la parseará usando otro formato que sea plausible. Me explico, si se encuentra con `05-17-2017` no va a lanzar una excepción sino que la parseará como `2017-05-17`.

Lo anterior no debe ser un problema siempre que estés seguro de la validez de tus fechas y que todas tienen el formato `dd-mm-aaaa`. Este es el aviso literal de la documentación:

> Warning: dayfirst=True is not strict, but will prefer to parse with day first (this is a known bug, based on dateutil behavior).

---

**Edición:**

Puedes parsear adecuadamente las columnas al cargar el csv directamente.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('PORFA.csv', header=0, sep=';',
                 parse_dates = ['FDE Date'], dayfirst = True )
```

A `parse_dates` le debes pasar en este caso los nombres de las columnas que debe parsear como fecha. Si fueran fechas no estándar debes usar el argumento `date_parser` pasandole una función que paresee la cadena a fecha válida.

Posteriormente puedes ordenar le DataFrame por fecha usando alguna de estas columnas:

```
df.sort_values(by="FDE Date", inplace = True)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si entiendo, pero en mi base de datos todas las fechas tienen el mismo orden o estructura. Saludos!

Comment: @JorgePonti solo dejé el aviso por si alguien usa la respuesta y se encuentra con esta situación. A veces te encuentras con csv que de congruentes tienen poco... XD. En tu caso esto no tiene importancia si sabes de primera mano que la columna es uniforme en cuanto al formato de las fechas. Lo que te pasaba a ti al principio era justo esto pero al contrario, intentaba parsear con el mes primero y cuando la fecha no era plausible lo intentaba con el dia primero, por eso no obtenias excepciones. Saludos.

Comment: se puede cargar la info ordenada cronológicamente?

Comment: @JorgePonti si te refieres a cargar el csv ordenado por una columna no porque es un archivo y hay que leerlo secuencialmente si o si. Ahora bién, una vez creado el dataframe con las columnas de fechas adecuadamente parseada puedes ordenar las filas usando una columna de fechas si quieres sin problemas: `df.sort_values(by="FDE Date", inplace = True)`

Comment: Claro, me refería a ordenar el CSV completo, ya que si ordenó después solo las fechas me genera indiscrepancia con otros dateframe que dependen de sus fechas.

Comment: @JorgePonti el código de mi mensaje anterior ordena el dataframe completo (ordena las filas) según las fechas de la columna `FDE DATE` (siempre que esta sea de tipo datetime, es decir, que ya esté parseada como fecha).

Comment: yo cargo el CSV así         "df = pd.read_csv('MMRExport6.csv', header=0, sep=';')", luego ordeno por fecha como dices       "df.sort_values(by="FDE Date", inplace = True)", pero mi fecha no es fecha aún ya que después la convierto a fecha así       "Date2=pd.to_datetime(df["FDE Date"],dayfirst = True)", por lo tanto no funcionaría. Debría cargarla desde un inicio como fecha cierto?

Comment: @JorgePonti, claro, si haces eso ordena como strings no como fechas. He editado la respuesta, mira al final. De esa forma parseas las columnas a fechas al cargar el csv directamente. Acuerdate de pasarle a `parse_dates` la lista con los nombres de las columnas que sean fechas. También podrias hacerlo posteriormente con `to_datetime` así: `df["FDE Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FDE Date"], dayfirst = True)` y luego ordenar, pero es menos eficiente.

Comment: Sabes que no ordena lo estoy haciendo como dices pero no ordena "df = pd.read_csv('MMRExport8.csv', header=0, sep=';',parse_dates = ['FDE Date'], dayfirst = True)"

Comment: Con eso no ordenas, solo lees. Despues de leer debes hacer: `df.sort_values(by="FDE Date", inplace = True)`. Asegurate que la columna "FDE Date" está bien parseada.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62862/discussion-between-jorge-ponti-and-fjsevilla).

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenia se debia a que las fechas estaban en formato dd/mm/aa y en el programa donde realizo la visualizacion de datos, por defecto toma el primer valor como mes, el segundo como dia, y el tercero como año. al utilizar la instruccion "inplace=True" en el momento de cargar el archivo CSV, lo organizo como esta explicado en este post